# Django Rest Framework with multiple Viewsets and Routers for the same object

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am having trouble defining different view sets for the same object using Django Rest Framework. Following is a minimal example to reproduce the issue, based on DRF Quickstart. I am using python 3.5 and the latest DRF.

**tutorial/quickstart/serializers.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email')

class UserMinimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username')
```

**tutorial/quickstart/views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets
from tutorial.quickstart.serializers import UserSerializer, UserMinimalSerializer

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class UserMinimalViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserMinimalSerializer
```

**tutorial/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from tutorial.quickstart import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'users-minimal', views.UserMinimalViewSet) 

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

When running the server and GETting the root, you end up with:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "users": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users-minimal/",
    "users-minimal": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users-minimal/"
}
```

Note both `users` and `users-minimal` point to `.../users-minimal/`.

Also, when accessing `http://HOST:PORT/users/` you get:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users-minimal/2/",
            "username": "user2",
            "email": "user2@users.com"
        },
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users-minimal/1/",
            "username": "user1,
            "email": "user1@users.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note the urls point to `.../users-minimal/`.

Final note: my question is somewhat similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533943/django-rest-framework-routers-with-multiple-viewsets), but the suggested solution did not work for me, nor did it suggest why it should work in the first place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer: You have to add the `basename` parameter to your route to `users-minimal`:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'users-minimal', UserMinimalViewSet, basename='usersminimal')
```

Normally DRF genereates a `basename` automatically from your `queryset`. 
This is explained in the [DRF routers docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/), search for `basename`.

Your two `Viewset`s use the same `queryset` so the have initially the same `basename`. That leads to the problems which you have seen, that the later registered `ViewSet` will overwrite the routes from the former registered `ViewSet`.
You can see this in action when you change the order of the `router.register` in your example.

You can see the base names of your routes when you test the code directly in the shell:

```
from rest_framework import routers
from tutorial.quickstart import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'users-minimal', views.UserMinimalViewSet)


> routers.urls
[<RegexURLPattern user-list ^minimal/$>,
<RegexURLPattern user-list ^minimal\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$>,
<RegexURLPattern user-detail ^minimal/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$>,
<RegexURLPattern user-detail ^minimal/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$>,
<RegexURLPattern user-list ^users/$>,
<RegexURLPattern user-list ^users\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$>,
<RegexURLPattern user-detail ^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$>,
<RegexURLPattern user-detail ^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$>,
<RegexURLPattern api-root ^$>,
<RegexURLPattern api-root ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$>]
```