# Register multiple routes in Django DRF - using and calling methods in ModelViewSets or Generics

Tags: python, django, generics, django-rest-framework, routes

I want to understand how to use Django DRF to register:

- two different endpoints, and
- only one endpoint making use of custom fields

Please show the differences in using ViewSets and Generics.

These are my attempts.

I came from **Flask**, and found very clear to define multiple end-points with decorators.

### Flask - example endpoints to get a list of objects,last object

#### option 1

```
@application.route('/people/', endpoint='people')
def people():
   # return a list of people
   pass

@application.route('/last/', endpoint='last_person')
def last_person():
   # return last person
   pass
```

#### option 2

```
@application.route('/people/', endpoint='people')
def people():
   field = request.args.get('last', None)
   if field:
      # return last person from list of people
   else:
     # return list of people
```

I understood the benefit of DRF may be consistency and read the documentation,
but found cumbersome and wish to understand more clearly how to make use of ModelsViewSets and Generics to see the benefits VS flask.

Please help with an example to fetch a list of users, and last user.

---

### Django DRF - first approach (ModelViewSet)

```
# serializer.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Person

class PersonSerializer( serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name', 'nickname', 'timestamp')
```

```
# views.py
class PersonViewSet( viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
```

I understood the class `PersonViewSet` should be ready to expose method to both fetch a list, as well as retrieve an item, because of `ModelViewSet`:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

But how to explicitly see that when registering the endpoints ?

Example:

```
# urls.py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'people', views.PersonViewSet)

app_name = 'myapi'

urlpatterns = [
   path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

When I browse `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/` , I can see only one endpoint.
Yes, if I try `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/1/` it will retrieve a user by itself, but how can I read it in the code above?
how can I map a method from `PersonViewSet` (something like `PersonViewSet.get_last_person()` ) to instruct using the same endpoint to get last entry ?

### Django DRF - second approach (Generics)

I read `Generics` models exposes APIs models suited to retrieve one single item, rather than a list:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview

I tried to add, in `views.py`:

```
# I make use of RetrieveAPIView now
class LastPersonView( generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
```

and in `urls.py`:

```
router.register(r'people', views.PersonViewSet)
router.register(r'last-person', views.LastPersonView)
```

But that will yield error:
AttributeError: type object 'LastPersonView' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions
because Generics does not have get_extra_actions , like instead ViewSet

How to register both views in my router, in this second example ?

### Django DRF - Third attempt (ModelViewSet with basename)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40759051/305883

I could also instruct a ViewSet to register different endpoints in my `urls.py` , by assigning a basename:

```
router.register(r'people', views.PersonViewSet)
router.register(r'last-person', views.PersonViewSet,  basename='lastperson')
```

and use the same `ModelViewSet`:

```
class PersonViewSet( viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
```

I understood the benefit of this approach is more "simple", because queryset is always the same.

But I can I register a method to retrieve the last object, and map that method in my router (`include(router.urls)`) ?

---

Could offer examples making use of ModelViewSets, Generics and a more explicit approach that declare methods in Views and call those methods in an endpoint ?

Could you illustrate which approach may be better:

- use a viewSet to handle lists, and expose a method to retrieve an item from the list
- use two separate views, one for a list, and one for an item
- map two distinct endpoints in my router from one single view or from two separate views
- map one endpoint with field options to my router , from one single view

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to go through each of the approaches you've taken and will provide a solution to meet your need to be based on that very approach. So let's roll ...

---

**Your first approach:**

Your first approach uses a very typical DRF setup with routes being generated for various actions for `PersonViewSet` by DRF itself.

Now, you need to add a new URL endpoint that will resolve to the last object of the `queryset`:

```
Person.objects.all().order_by('name')
```

and presumably, the endpoint should reside under the `person` basename.

We can leverage the `action` decorator in here to map HTTP GET on a certain URL to be mapped to a method in the viewset and from that method we can set the `kwargs` attribute of the viewset instance to set `pk` to that of the last object, and finally send the request to the `retrieve` method itself e.g.:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action

class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer

    @action(
        methods=['get'],
        detail=False,
        url_path='last',
        url_name='last',
    )
    def get_last_person(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        last_pk = self.queryset.all().last().pk 
        self.kwargs.update(pk=last_pk)
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now if you request on the `/people/last/` endpoint you would get the response for the last retrieved object.

Note that, if you have `lookup_url_kwargs` and `lookup_field` different than `pk`, you need to use set those in `kwargs` as you can imagine. Also, you can put the operations for `retrieve` yourself rather than delegating to `retrieve` but let's keep it *DRY*.

FWIW, if you want to have this endpoint for PUT/PATCH/DELETE as well, you need to add the methods in `action` and delegate them to respective actions based on the method name.

---

**Your second approach:**

Views are not ViewSets (check out the base classes of both: `rest_framework.views.View` and `rest_framework.viewsets.ViewSet`); DRF routers create endpoints for viewsets, not views. There are ways to turn views into viewsets, basically just by inheriting from `viewsets.GenericViewSet` -- which it turn inherits from `viewsets.ViewSetMixin` and `generics.GenericAPIView`.

`viewsets.ViewSetMixin` has the actual *magic* that turns views into viewsets by providing all the necessary action-method mapping in the `as_view` classmethod.

To make this approach to work, we need to define a `retrieve` method that sends the response from the serializer:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.response import Response

class LastPersonView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):

    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    queryset = Person.objects.all().order_by('name')

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.queryset.all().last()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

`generics.RetrieveAPIView`'s `get` method delegates the request to the `retrieve` method hence we've overridden `retrieve` here.

Now, we need to define the route as a regular endpoint, not in a DRF router:

```
urlpatterns = router.urls + [
    path('last-person/', LastPersonView.as_view()),
]
```

---

**Your third approach:**

You've registered two different prefixes for the same viewset (again using view here wouldn't work, must be a viewset), so two different set of URL mappings with all the same CRUD operations. I don't think this is not what you want based on your expectations so I'm not going to discuss this approach further but I think you get the idea from above why it's not relevant.

---

Now, if I have to choose, I would prefer the first approach as everything is under the same viewset, prefix and basename, and you don't need to muck around with the URLConf.

I hope the above clarifies a thing or two.

Comment: Beautifully explained @heemayl! Thank you, very clear. 
Can I ask you to comment about a couple of points, one to help me understand better how things works, and the other for coding style.

About the first, how is a serializer applied to the queryset ? I mean, it is not a function applied to something, it is a class. It is a bit obscure to me how the object is seriealised and then passed on to a request. Example, in the second method, `retrieve ` apply a serialiser to an instance, but in the first method it is not necessary to use `.get_serialiser()` .. how thing works under the hood?

Comment: The second comment is about styling code.
One can have different endpoints (some for JSON response, some for HTML templates) wrapped up under the same viewset, and so may want to use different paths, like: `/api/people/last_name` (JSON) and a `/greeting` page (HTML) consuming the other api.

How would you instruct `/myapp/url.py` to do so ? 

Or would you create two classes with the second method that you shown, for clarity ?

I posted a question about it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59009504/methods-from-a-single-view-to-different-endpoints-keep-apis-for-html-and-for-js

Comment: @user305883 These are broad topics that actually require their own answers but in short the initializer of the serializer class (see `BaseSerailizer`) only initializes the queryset/instance and other values passed as serializer instance's attributes for easy retrieval later. And `serializer.data` is actually a `property` that uses `to_representation` method of the serializer (which in turn call each field's one) to get a serialized response. (1)

Comment: @user305883  In the first approach, we called `self.retrieve` which does the serialization itself so we don't have to worry, while in the second case we needed to to that ourselves as we've returned the response back directly from there. (2)

Comment: @user305883 Regarding your second question, I'd try to put an answer on your new question once I have some time.

Comment: @user305883 Glad, I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can accomplish what you do in flask creating a `list_route` o a `detail_route` through the `@action` decorator in your `ViewSet`. The router will create for you the endpoint based on the name of the function. For example

```
class PersonViewSet( viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=['post']) # detail route
    def set_password(self, request, pk=None):
        # your code

    @action(detail=False) # list route
    def last_person(self, request):
       # your code
```

this code will create a `people/last_person` and a `people/<id>/set_password`
For more information about how the router creates the paths: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routing-for-extra-actions
Using this extra action allow you to have different serializer for different actions and so have different fields exposed.

Here some clarification about your doubts:

- A `ModelViewSet` is only a "shortcut" that you can use when you want to expose a complete CRUD interface for your model. It's based on the `GenericsViewSet` and other mixins and you have the chance to write a very little amount of code to make it work appropriately. If you don't have a model, then you should use the `ViewSet` to build your API. If you only want to expose some operations, for example, only list or retrieve, you can build-up your API using the mixins, in this case `mixins.ListModelMixin` and  `mixins.RetrieveModelMixin` and the `GenericViewSet`
- Instead, the generics that you're using are only `View`, not `ViewSet`. This means that you cannot register them through the router. You should add them directly to the Django URLs, like any other view. As per drf documentation:

  > Django REST framework allows you to combine the logic for a set of related views in a single class, called a ViewSet.

Doc to viewset https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/, doc to view https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/

- The `basename` doesn't prevent you from writing two different `ViewSet`. If you use the same `ViewSet` you'll have the same functionality at two different endpoint

Comment: Thank you Fran for clarifying a bit. I used ```@action```in the ModelViewSet . Could you give an example of use case when not having a model for using Generics, and one for using "detail" set to True ? About documenting the APIs: in the DRF page, I can see my API: ```127.0.0.1:8000/api```listing the endpoint at root base. How to know which paths are allowed for that endpoint ? 
As example, I see `/api/people/` , how do I know that `/api/people/1/` or `/api/people/last_person/` are allowed? I could only see two endpoints if I registered different `ModelViewSet` in the router. Thank you!

Comment: 1) Here is an article that uses `ViewSet` with a non-model example https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/#advanced-customization (sorry, yesterday I wrote `GenericViewSet` instead of `ViewSet`, but now I've corrected the answer. `GenericViewSet` also provide model related functionalities)
2) In my answer, there is the `set_password` as an example of a `datail=True` action. The idea is to use it for actions related to a particular instance.
3) Here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/#advanced-customization more info to customize your API doc

Comment: Thank you @Fran, kind of you to follow up and share other references!