# Methods from a single view to different endpoints: keep APIs for HTML and for JSON separated (Django Rest Framework)

Tags: python, django, api, templates, django-rest-framework

Could you help suggesting how to keep coding style organised to keep endpoints from HTML and JSON separated, in Django Rest Framework ?

In Flask I am used to keeps endpoints for serving Json, and ones for serving HTML, separated, like:

```
@application.route('/api/')
def api_root():
    #...
    return jsonify({'data' : data})
```

and

```
@application.route('/home/<string:page>/', endpoint='page_template')
    #...
   return render_template(template, page)
```

And so I could serve the APIs like:

```
/api/page => serve the json for the page, say for AJAX etc.
/page => serve the corresponding html page
```

In Django RF, I read that a ModelViewSet can serve both.

So I could keep everything in one place.

However, when I come to map views on the router, I would have all the endpoint served respect the path related my model, they would be all sub-path of `/api`

Could you help in advising a good coding practice to make use of ModelViewSet, and route endpoints for html separated from APIs ?

This is the example Im working on, my doubts are in comments:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .serializers import PersonSerializer
from .models import Person

class PersonViewSet( viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer

    # this will return last person
    # I can see it registered at: 127.0.0.1:8000/api/people/last_person/
    @action(detail=False) 
    def last_person(self, request):
        queryset = Person.objects.all().order_by('timestamp').reverse()[0]
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    # this will return a template:
    # I can see it registered at: ../api/people/greetings : I wanted at /greetings
    @action(detail=False)
    def greetings(self, request):

        queryset = Person.objects.all().order_by('timestamp').reverse()[0]
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset)

        return render(
            request,
            'myapi/greetings.html',
            {
                'person': serializer.data
            }
        )
```

Also, please note how I am serving the method `greetings`: here I am repeating the queryset and serialising part. I thought to do:

```
def greetings(self, request):

        person = self.last_person(request)
        return render(
            request,
            'myapi/greetings.html',
            {
                'person': person
            }
        )
```

But it will give error, because `person`would be a `Response` object, and could not find a way to pass it to the `render`.

Which could be a good coding style to avoid replicating things, and keep APIs and templates separated ?

In `/myapi/url.py` I am registered the endpoints like:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'people', views.PersonViewSet)

app_name = 'myapi'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

In the main `url.py`, like this:

```
from django.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('myapi.urls')),
    path('', include('myapi.urls'))  # How to keep views for templates and for Json separated ??
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything before the response phase is the same, you should not touch anything except renderers. You can provide a response in the desired format by choosing the right renderer based on user's request, precisely on the media-type -- **`Accept`** header.

For example, let's say you want to send a JSON and HTML response based on the media-type (`Accept` header). So when you pass *(passing only one media-type to keep the example simple)*:

- `Accept: application/json` it should return reponse in JSON
- `Accept: text/html` it should return HTML response

Before moving with the implementation, let's discuss first how DRF handles renderers:

- Renderers can be defined globally in `settings.py` as `DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES` collection or on a per view (viewsets are technically views with the method-action mappings and associated logics) basis as `renderer_classes` class attribute.
- The order of renderers is very important. DRF chooses the most specific renderer based on the `Accept` value. For more generic one or for catch-all (`*/*`) the first renderer that satisfies media-type is chosen.
- if you use DRF's `DefaultRouter` for URL mappings, you can also use the `format` extension to filter out any renderer that does not support the passed format. For example, if you have an endpoint `/foo/1/`, you can add a format like `/foo/1.json/`. Then only the renderer classes that have `format = json` as an attribute will be selected (and then the final selection mentioned in the earlier point will take place only among these renderers).

So based on the above, from the API consumer, you need to pass the correct `Accept` header and if using `DefaultRouter` also better to add the `format` extension to do the pre-filtering on the renderers.

On the API, do:

- define renderer classes in the correct order as mentioned earlier
- if the consumer passes `format`, makes sure the renderer has the format name as an attribute
- *if you send the response yourself*, make sure you use the `Response` (`rest_framework.response.Response`) class which passes the correct renderer context and calls the `render` method of the renderer to send the correct response back

If you want to send a JSON response, you can actually leverage the `JSONRenderer` (`rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer`) which serves the purpose perfectly. If you want to customize only a few things, you can create your own subclassing `JSONRenderer`.

In the case of sending an HTTP response, you can take inspiration from the `TemplateHTMLRenderer` (`rest_framework.renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer`) or extend it to meet your needs. It has the boilerplate:

```
media_type = 'text/html'
format = 'html'
template_name = None
exception_template_names = [
    '%(status_code)s.html',
    'api_exception.html'
]
charset = 'utf-8'
```

and the data passed in by the serializer is already available as the template context. So you can set the `template_name` above (or pass in with `Response` if you're overriding) and add all HTML representations there. You can also override `render` to have more customization there if you want.

And eventually, if you feel like making a custom one yourself, [the DRF doc is pretty awesome in explaining what you need to do](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#custom-renderers).

Comment: Hi @heemayl, apologise for not coming back here earlier, im under deadlines :|. I wanted to thank you once more for your answer and clarity, you are good at explaining things! I sensed empathy, a very important thing to me, especially when "virtualising" relationships out of looking often the same "viewport" of the laptop.. ahah ..) I looked at your profile: my congratulations! (p.s. YNWA + PinkFloyed are awesome)   |_|/

Comment: @user305883 Thank you very much for your kind words, it means a lot! YNWA and PF -- yeah :)