# Django Rest Framework: incorrect hyperlink on second viewset of same model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to provide two distinct APIs using DRF but I'm unable to get the second app to stop creating 
hyperlinked references based on the first. It's essentially the same problem as [Django Rest Framework with multiple Viewsets and Routers for the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758373/django-rest-framework-with-multiple-viewsets-and-routers-for-the-same-object/) but I'm unable to get it working.

`app1/urls.py`:

```
router = SimpleRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(prefix=r'article', viewset=app1.ArticleViewSet, basename=r'article')
urlpatterns = [path(f'', include(router.urls)]
```

`app2/urls.py`:

```
router = SimpleRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(prefix=r'published', viewset=app2.ArticleViewSet, basename=r'published')
urlpatterns = [path(f'', include(router.urls)]
```

`site/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('app1/', include('app1.urls')),
    path('app2/', include('app2.urls')),
]
```

While both viewsets are of the same model, the queryset & serializer for each is different.

When I GET an item from `/app2/published`, it has an `app1` URL:

```
"url": "http://localhost:8000/app1/article/5461"
```

What I'm wanting is for items retrieved via `app2` to have:

```
"url": "http://localhost:8000/app2/published/5461"
```

From looking at the docs, it appears that providing `basename` should do what I want, but I'm not having any luck with getting it to work.

Comment: Your serializer generates that URL, can you show that and at a minimum the meta + url field in the serializer?  If you haven't declared the url field manually then you will need to, in order to tell it which route to `reverse`.

Comment: Glad it helped!  Go ahead and create an answer for the question, for others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code in your `site/urls.py`:

```
from app1.urls import router as app1_router
from app2.urls import router as app2_router

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.registry.extend(app1_router.registry)
router.registry.extend(app2_router.registry)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)), # default page to show api
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))  
]
```

You can see an example [here](https://repl.it/@saif935775/Django-Template#mysite/urls.py), which has same structure as you need.